# VLOOKUP does not return a result

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Well, i created a userform with two fields.
One is a combobox used as dropdown list for text values like "living room" "kitchen" "bath room" ...
second one is a text box.
in this text box i want to display the room code for the room names

i created the form

- combobox is called RoomNames
- textbox is called RoomTypes

i have a "LIBRARY" worksheet

- column 1 = RoomTypes (integer values from 1 to n)
- column 3 = RoomNames (text)

i have a "ROOMBOOK"

here i want to add slected RoomTypes and RoomNames

when i use a for loop and compare with an if statement the code is working as expected and the result is a RoomTypes code for each of my RoomNames. 
the output to "ROOMBOOK" also works as expected.

when i use VLOOKUP i only receive type mismatch errors.
here the code

```
Private Sub InsertButton_Click()
'find last filled row
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ROOMBOOK").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
' get text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ROOMBOOK").Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = RoomNames.Text

Me.RoomTypes = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RoomNames.Text, Worksheets("LIBRARY").Range("A5:C50"), 1, 0)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ROOMBOOK").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = RoomTypes.Text
End Sub
```

results in runtime error 1004 for the VLookup statement

any help appreciated

Comment: Try using `Me.RoomTypes.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your wording you seem to be trying and use VLOOKUP in a sort of "backwards" mode (findi a match in third column and return the corresponding value in first column) which isn't allowed

use `Match()` function to get the index of the found value and then use it as rowIndex parameter in a `Cells(rowIndex, colIndex)` context:

```
Me.RoomTypes.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LIBRARY").Range("A5:A50").Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.RoomNames.Text, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LIBRARY").Range("C5:C50"), 0), 1)
```

BTW you should get in the habit of use *explicit* `Range` qualifications up to `Workbook` object, an example of which is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub InsertButton_Click()
    Dim lastrow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook ' reference wanted workbook
        Me.RoomTypes.Text = .Worksheets("LIBRARY").Range("A5:A50").Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.RoomNames.Text, .Worksheets("LIBRARY").Range("C5:C50"), 0), 1)

        With .Worksheets("ROOMBOOK") 'reference wanted worksheet of referenced workbook
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'find last not empty cell row index in referenced worksheet column B
            .Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = Me.RoomTypes.Text
            .Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = RoomNames.Text
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: my problem now: the cell content is multi lines, how can that be solved ?

Comment: start a new question with proper explanations and showing your coding efforts